# Table traversing with multiple operations in ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, innodb

Some databases, like MySQL *[1]* and PostgreSQL *[2]*, support bundling of certain compatible ALTER TABLE statements (as non-standard SQL).

For example we can have:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
    DROP COLUMN `column_1`,
    DROP COLUMN `column_2`,
    ...
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE
    MODIFY `column_1` ... ,
    MODIFY `column_2` ... ,
```

instead of having individual statements:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` DROP COLUMN `column_1`;
ALTER TABLE `my_table` DROP COLUMN `column_2`;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` MODIFY `column_1` ... ;
ALTER TABLE `my_table` MODIFY `column_2` ... ;
```

etc

For comparison of the same feature, PostgreSQL *[2]*, which also implements this, will perform all operations in a single scan:

> The main reason for providing the option to specify multiple changes in a single ALTER TABLE is that multiple table scans or rewrites can thereby be combined into a single pass over the table.

Although for DROP COLUMN specifically it will often not even need do that:

> The DROP COLUMN form does not physically remove the column, but simply makes it invisible to SQL operations...

**Questions:**

- Would the multi-column statement result in traversing all the rows just once and performing all changes needed?
- How does MySQL actually perform DROP COLUMN? Does it also "hide" the columns first, or does it delete the data straight away?

Assumptions:

- Using InnoDB
- No indexes/complex defaults are involved in any of the columns we want to change/drop (so basically changes that would not require  a temporary table when run as individual alter statements)

References:

- *[1]* [MySQL ALTER TABLE docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)
- *[2]* [PostgreSQL ALTER TABLE docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: For your first question, in my experience doing one ALTER TABLE with many columns is faster than a separate alter for each, indicating MySQL does "bundle" the operation into one table re-creation. For you second question, the documentation you've already linked covers that. "While ALTER TABLE is executing, the original table is readable by other sessions (with the exception noted shortly)."

Comment: (Syntax: It's `MODIFY COLUMN`...)

Comment: Hi @Uueerdo, thanks! I'm not sure how this part of the docs answers my second question, unless it is implicitly? I found an explicit answer in the ddl docs for InnoDB, it looks like drop column performs a (fairly expensive) in-place rebuild.

Comment: @Geekfish I meant in the sense that if the original table is still readable until the alter completes, the drop column must not hide the columns before they are dropped.

Comment: Aah I see, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some useful feedback but decided to respond to my own question to provide a more concrete set of answers.

> Would the multi-column statement result in traversing all the rows just once and performing all changes needed?

**Yes**, if the alter statement results in rebuilding the table then it only needs to do it once.*

* This answer comes from my own testing and other mostly anecdotal evidence (including @Uueerdo 's in this post). It would be useful to have some official docs for this...

> How does MySQL actually perform DROP COLUMN? Does it also "hide" the columns first, or does it delete the data straight away?

MySQL will rebuild the table in place (rather than create a copy or just change metadata) for most column operations. Each specific case can be found in the [Online DDL docs for InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#online-ddl-column-operations).

A few operations like renaming a column or setting a default value will just alter metadata, so they don't require a table rebuild.

However, **dropping a column DOES require a full table rebuild**.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's InnoDB:

(This does *not* really answer the Questions, but provides a little more insight in the the bigger question of `ALTER`.)

- If any of the alters needs to copy the table over, you are *probably* better off putting all alters into the same statement.  Changing the `PRIMARY KEY`, for example, requires rebuilding the data that is clustered with the PK.
- Some alters can be achieved by simply altering the schema; these are virtually instantaneous, and could be done via separate alter statements.  Adding an option to `ENUM` was implemented long ago.
- Some alters need some form of scan, but can do it "in the background".  `DROP INDEX` can be done by quickly "hiding" it, then freeing up the BTree in the background.
- I have left out a grey area in which you batch 'simple' alters.  One would hope that `ALTER` is smart enough to simply go through them quickly, rather than deciding to copy the table over.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I managed to find some explanations in the InnoDB docs in the end (see my answer below). Most operations are done with an in-place rebuild, with the comment "Data is reorganized substantially, making it an expensive operation.". However, bundling alters should be advantageous for both in-place and full-copy strategies.